# Campo de pesquisa com borda arredondada

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de fazer um `input` de pesquisa adjacente a um botão com uma borda arredondada que encaixe um no outro da seguinte forma:

[image: Pesquisa]

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso com `CSS` puro, de preferência sem utilizar o campo de pesquisa por cima do botão?

Comment: Pode ser usando um `div` editável?

Comment: @RicardoPontual não entendi bem o que seria... mas não sei, eu só preciso fazer esse campo de busca aí e não sei nada de design hahaha

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda https://jsfiddle.net/6kzLud4v/   Fiz rapidinho no fiddle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode usar o `border-radius`.

```css
.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #0699CD;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.content {
  background: #33CB33;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.content input {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #82CCE6;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 70%;
  border: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.content button {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <input type="text">
    <button>Pesquisar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tenho que dizer que estou impressionado...

Comment: Caso tenha ajudado, por marcar como resposta de sua dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

Como vc falou que não queria o `input` ficando por cima do `button` fiz esse modelo simples. A dica aqui é que o `box-shadow` do btn é que fica por baixo do `input` dando a impressão que é uma coisa só.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: #0699CD;
}
.search-bar {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.search-bar input {
    width: 75%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: #82CCE6;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-radius: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.search-bar button {
    background-color: #33CB33;
    box-shadow: -50px 0 0 0 #33CB33;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="search-bar">
    <input type="text" value="teste">
    <button type="submit">pesquisar ></button>
</nav>
```